# Rails enum: public and private

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is it possible to create an enum like this in Rails?

```
enum status: [:public, :private]
```

Cause throw me an error saying that a public method will be create to this enum, and makes sense, so I will have something like this:

```
object.public!
```

For example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately not, ActiveRecord won't allow you to define an enum with `public` or `private` (or `new`, etc.) because they're reserved method names. There have been [issues](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/14160) reported for this, but they're closed as won't fix.

If your status enum is simply `public` or `private`, then it may make more sense to store that as a boolean. You can create a couple of methods to act like they're a enum to do what you want. In your model:

```
def public!
  self.public = true
end

def private!
  self.public = false
end
```

Don't forget if you create a boolean column to set a default:

```
add_column :people, :public, :boolean, default: false
```

Comment: Thanks man, I wasnt fouding anything related to this. Anyways, thanks for the suggestion!